# Backbone JS Template Printing only last item in the collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am facing a problem with my backbone view. I am trying to render an array of day objects and each day object contains another array of time objects. I get the collection from my API just fine, but once its rendered it shows this:

[image]

Which is basically the last item of my collection as I can see from my console. The API call actually returns valid output.

This is what my template looks like:

```
<table id="stbl" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
     <% _.each(slots, function(slot) { %>
              <tr>
                <td>
                   <strong> <%- slot.startDate %> </strong>
                </td>
                <% _.each(slot.timeSlots, function(t) { %>
                    <td>
                       <button id="le-time" class="btn btn-primary"><%- t %></button>
                    </td>
                <% }); %>
               </tr>
         <% }); %>
</table>
```

And this is my collection:

```
kronos.Slots = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: kronos.Slot,
    url: '/api/freeslots'
});
```

And this is what my view looks like:

```
kronos.TableView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        var self = this;
        this.collection.fetch({
            success: function (collection, response) {
                _.each(response, function (i) {
                    console.log(i);
                });
                self.render();
            },
            data: $.param({ orgID: 4 })
        });
        this.collection.on('reset', this.render, this);
    },
    template: _.template($('#slotsTable').html()),
    render: function () {
        $('#slotsContainer').html(this.template({
            slots: this.collection.toJSON()
        }));
    }
});
```

JSON data returned by the fetch call

```
[
    {"id":0, "startDate":"04/11/2013", "serviceID":241, "providerID":223, "timeSlots": ["09:00","10:00","11:00","12:00","13:00","14:00","15:00","16:00"]},
    {"id":0, "startDate":"05/11/2013", "serviceID":241, "providerID":223, "timeSlots": ["09:00","10:00","11:00","12:00","13:00","14:00","15:00","16:00"]}
]
```

Can you please help me understand what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: If interested here is what the json output actually looks like upon the fetch call https://gist.github.com/aliirz/7291134-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When fetching data in a collection, Backbone will perform a [collection.set](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-set) with the data:

> **set** collection.set(models, [options])
>   The set method performs a "smart" update of the collection with the passed list of models. If a
>   model in the list isn't yet in the collection it will be added; if the
>   model is already in the collection its attributes will be merged; and
>   if the collection contains any models that aren't present in the list,
>   they'll be removed.

All your models have the same id, 0, which seems to hopelessly confuse Backbone : see this demo http://jsfiddle.net/T3fmx/

To solve your quandary, you can either:

- remove the `id` attribute from the server response or assign unique values, http://jsfiddle.net/T3fmx/3/
- set a fake `idAttribute` in your model : http://jsfiddle.net/T3fmx/1/

  ```
  kronos.Slot = Backbone.Model.extend({
      idAttribute: 'whatever'
  });
  ```
- parse the data returned to omit the `id` attribute : http://jsfiddle.net/T3fmx/2/

  ```
  kronos.Slot = Backbone.Model.extend({
      parse: function(data) {
          return _.omit(data, 'id');
      }
  });
  ```