# Backbone Collection View is only rendering last object in the collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to place the rendered output of a Collection View onto the dom. However, only the last object in the collection is displayed on the page at the end of the process.

I have a event handler set up on the view so that when an item is clicked, it's `title` is logged out. Whenever I click on this single element that is placed onto the Dom, the title for each of my objects is logged, even though only one is displayed, so each handler is being applied to the final element but is somehow logging out the correct titles.

Does anybody know how I can render out each item in the collection rather than just the final one? Below is a quick tour through my code.

The end goal is to list out the name of each film.

## Model

First, define the model - nothing exciting here

```
var FilmModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

## View

Here is a simplified version of the View I have made for the Film model

```
var FilmView = Backbone.View.extend({

  // tagName: 'li',

  initialize: function() {
    this.$el = $('#filmContainer');
  },

  events: {
    'click': 'alertName'
  },

  alertName: function(){
    console.log("User click on "+this.model.get('title'));
  },

  template: _.template( $('#filmTemplate').html() ),

  render: function(){
    this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.attributes ) );
    return this;
  }

});
```

## Collection

Again, seems standard.

```
var FilmList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: FilmModel,
});
```

## Collection View

Adapted from a Codeschool course I took on Backbone

```
var FilmListView = Backbone.View.extend({
  // tagName: 'ul',

  render: function(){
    this.addAll();
    return this;
  },

  addAll: function(){
    this.$el.empty();
    this.collection.forEach(this.addOne, this);
  },

  addOne: function(film){
    var filmView = new FilmView( { model: film } );
    this.$el.append(filmView.render().el);
    // console.log(this.$el);
  }

});
```

## Go time

```
var filmList = new FilmList({});

var filmListView = new FilmListView({
  collection: filmList
});


var testFilms = [
  {title: "Neverending Story"},
  {title: "Toy Story 2"}
];

filmList.reset(testFilms);

filmListView.render();
```

From my understanding of Backbone so far, what this should be doing is appending, using the template specified in FilmView to render each item in the filmList collection into the el in the filmListView.

However, what actually happens is that the final title is always placed on the DOM.

I initially (when this was pulling in from an API) thought that the issue might be similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19754293/backbone-js-template-printing-only-last-item-in-the-collection), however now that I am resetting with my own testFilms, I can be positive that I am not overriding or setting any `id` attribute that I shouldn't.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: i think it could be that you set the el of FilmView to an id, which should always be unique, however then you loop over the collection and continually reset that el/id with the current model since each FilmView is going to have the same el

Comment: @Lbatson You got it - thanks for the that! I've removed that from the FilmView and am instead setting the FilmListView's el to be #filmContainer.
Thanks!

Comment: @lbatson if you'd like to post that as an Answer, I'll accept it so you get +rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it could be that you set the el of FilmView to an id, which should always be unique, however then you loop over the collection and continually reset that el/id with the current model since each FilmView is going to have the same el

Comment: I think this is more or less right. The code appears to be trying to render each model twice: once in `FilmView.prototype.render` and again in the call to `this.$el.append` in `FilmListView.prototype.addOne`. Of course, you only need one of these. This answer applies to the `render` method. `append` shouldn't suffer from overwriting of previously rendered HTML. However, the `FilmListView` object doesn't know which HTML element to attach to. Maybe it's attaching to a jQuery object which isn't in the DOM, so isn't visible, but could be added later.

Comment: You're right. the `FilmListView` should have the id, which i believe @Cian Mac Mahon has now updated. Since the `FilmView` was using the same id each time `this.$el = $('#filmContainer');` then `render` set the `html()` to the current model on each iteration of the collection so it was being overriden.

Comment: Yep, this was the answer, I was setting the element in the FilmView rather than the FilmListView due to an earlier stage in this project where I wasn't yet using collections. Thanks for the help!